# How can `document.execCommand()` copy a special text?

Tags: javascript

`document` has the `execCommand` function, in it there is `copy` property:

[`document.execCommand('copy');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

But I want to copy a special text, how can I realize it?

Such as:

```
var text = "abc123"
document.execCommand('copy', xxx) // or whatever to copy the text to the clipboard.
```

Comment: `document.execCommand("copy")` copies the selected text to the clipboard.  Are you saying you want to copy something else to the clipboard?

Comment: You can't, `execCommand('copy')` copies the selected content of a current editable element, it is not capable to copy some text from a JS variable. Except the case you can add the "special text" to an element, and then select the text and exec.